# SP 2007- using CQWP

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to use CQWP (content Query Web Part- SP 2007)using a custom list (Risk Management list).  I use this list on all the sub sites which I need to roll up in a single view.  Can this be achieved using CQWP.  When I add this web part and modify the web part, I don't see my custom list as an option.  I am able to use CQWP for an OOTB list (e.g. Project task), but not for a custom list that I create.

I appreciate any help I can get on this topic.  I've been struggling for the longest time.

Comment: Did your custom lists happen to use a custom ContentType?

Comment: No, not this list in particular.

Comment: Just a site note,when I use custom list option, it pulls items from all custom lists, not just this particular list that I'm looking to rollup

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to create a custom Site Content Type at the root of the site collection that consists of all of your required fields and then add that to each list, copying data as necessary and deleting the old columns.  Once that is in place, you can easily configure the CQWP to aggregate that content from anywhere in the site collection.

Using custom Content Types for grouping common fields is a Best Practice for reasons just like this (among others)

Comment: I created Site content type at the site collection level. Created custom list on 2 sub sites and added the content type to the list. Added CQWP to the parent site. Here are the settings:  Show items from all sites in this site collection (also tried show items from the following site and all sub sites), show items from custom list , and content type is the name I just created.  What am I missing?  it doesn't work for some reason.  Again, thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have data in the fields associated with the content type?

Comment: Yes, I added 2 entries to each list I created.

Comment: Also, if you are using non-standard fields, you may have to map them to what the CQWP understands.  When configuring the web part, look down under Presentation for a block titled `Fields to display`.  That block lists the attributes that the current XML used in the transform can understand.  You will need to map your custom field names there.

Comment: I don't see any block titled field under Presentation.. I give up on this.  Just wasted too much time behind it and not getting anywhere.. thanks for your help though